# Matlab - plotting multiple graphs with a constantly updating vector

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, axis

I am doing an exercise regarding particle generation and absorption. What i need to do it graph the total number of particles generated vs. absorbed. The number rises linearly, 10 per second, while the number absorbed are stored in a logical vector, so taking the sum of this gives the total number of absorbed. How can i, within the same script, make a second plot (first plot is the particle movement), to show the graph of created vs absorbed.

Thanks

Comment: Well, what do you have?  Which part do you not know how to do?  Do you know how to plot things ...?  It is hard to say anything meaningful when we don't know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I agree with above. It is of particular importance to know what type of plot you need. Multiple axes, scatter plot, do you want a colormap, ... We cannot help you without a detailed specification (or even better showing what you have attempted so we can easier grasp what you are after).

Comment: Take a look at the `drawnow` command. This will allow you to plot what you want every iteration and force the plots to be drawn immediately. While your `for`- or `while`-loop(s) run over all iterations, the plots will update continuously and look like they are being drawn live/on-line.